# Regular Expression capturing unwanted numbers from a text file

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am very new to python and regex.I am trying to extract phone numbers from a text file using python. The numbers can be in the format 0321-2695224 or 03212695224.

```
number_list = re.findall("03[0-6][0-9][-]?[0-9]{7}",numbers)
```

This should only return numbers with 11 digits, but this expression is also returning numbers which have more than 11 digits. In my file there is a number 0344446568956565 and this expression is returning 03444465689. What I want my expression to do is to completely ignore the numbers which have more than 11 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex which will only match 11 digit numbers which may optionally have hyphen `-` between any of the numbers,

```
(?<!\d)\d(?:-?\d){10}(?!\d)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\d)` - Number shouldn't be preceded by a digit
- `\d` - Starts matching with a digit
- `(?:-?\d){10}` - Further matches ten digits which may have a optional hyphen before the digit
- `(?!\d)` - Matched number shouldn't be followed by a digit to avoid matching larger numbers than eleven digits

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YPCj3P/1/)**

Python code,

```
import re

s = 'sometext 0321-2695224 something else 03212695224 something else further 0344446568956565'
print(re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d(?:-?\d){10}(?!\d)', s))
```

Prints only your intended numbers,

```
['0321-2695224', '03212695224']
```